# JQuery Jtable css paging selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-jtable

I am using Jquery JTable.

I have trouble with the pagination.
The numbers on the selects "Go to Page" and "Row Count" are not correctly displayed.

http://it.tinypic.com/r/aadljm/8

[image]

How can I fix it?
Thanks,Nk

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what does "not correctly displayed" means. What is your desired effect?

Comment: Like this: [Official Jtable demo]:http://oi59.tinypic.com/34glf8g.jpg

Comment: gotcha. Post the html and css that you have so far that is related to this

Comment: The problem is in bootstrap css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap css, add:

```
<style>
    select {
        color:black !important;
    }
</style>
```